# Limit as x approaches zero:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

[image: Limit problem here]

The limit is a solution to $$f(t)*f''(t)=c=0$$which arises when proving that Poisson's equation is unique. If Poisson's equation is indeed unique, $$\lim_{c\to 0}f(t)=0\,.$$

Further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_theorem_for_Poisson%27s_equation

How can I demonstrate that the above limit does, in fact, approach $0$ as parameter c approaches $0$?

Comment: When it has `[...][1]` just put an exclamation mark in front like this: `![...][1]` and it should work.  Though I haven't tried this on a low-rep account... someone want to verify this for me?

Comment: I'll give it a try with a temporary dummy question, and get back to you thereafter. Thanks for linking the image directly to the post +Simply Beautiful Art.

Comment: What's $k_1$ in the image above?

Comment: Also, to reply to a user on this site, use the `at symbol`, followed by their username with no spaces. @user491258

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt k1 and k2 are constants of integration, which may be solved for if appropriate boundary conditions are provided.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Post experiment: the ! in front of [...][1] works perfectly, thanks.

Comment: No problem! $\ddot\smile$ silly stackexchange restrictions lol.

Comment: The image you posted shows an equation with something in brackets being squared.  It is, however, ambiguous, what exactly is being squared.  Is the result of the $erf^{-1}$ being squared or the expression it operates on ?  It would help if you wrote out a corrected expression using MathJax.

Comment: @StephenG the entire inverse error distribution/function is squared. In general, g(x)^2 = [g(x)]^2, which is an unfortunate happenstance of the Wolfram language.